# Clarification needed for synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am learning about multithreading in Java. I am a bit confused with how threads accesses methods using the synchronized keyword as I am finding conflicating tutorials on how and which threads can access them. So just to share my current knowledge:

- Every object we create has a monitor/lock associated to it
- Any time a thread access a synchronized method, it needs to have the lock of the object/instance that it's trying to invoke
- A thread can relenquish a lock via the wait() method within a synchronized block.
- Once a thread calls notify/notifyAll, it wakes up the threads that called the wait() method.

So I've made a dummy program to highlight something i was curious about as i was getting mixed answers in the tutorials (unless i didn't understand it properly)..

Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Operation operation = new Operation();

    Thread tOne = new Thread(new OperationProcessor(operation));
    Thread tTwo = new Thread(new OperationProcessor(operation));
    Thread tThree = new Thread(new OperationProcessor(operation));
    Thread tFour = new Thread(() -> {
        for(int i =0 ; i < 500; i ++){
            operation.subtract();
        }
    });

    tOne.start();
    tTwo.start();
    tThree.start();
    tFour.start();

    tOne.join();
    tTwo.join();
    tThree.join();

    System.out.println(operation.counter);
}
}
```

Operation:

```
public class Operation {

int counter = 0;

public synchronized void add(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " reading the value: " + counter);
    counter++; //same as counter = counter + 1;
}

public void subtract(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " in the subtract method.");
}
}
```

Operation Processor:

```
public class OperationProcessor implements Runnable {
private final Operation operation;

public OperationProcessor(Operation operation) {
    this.operation = operation;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        operation.add();
    }
}
}
```

What I tried to do is test if different threads can call other non-synchronized methods AT THE SAME TIME as other threads calling other synchronized methods in the same instance of the object? E.g. if Thread1-3 are calling the add() method in turn (due to the lock), can Thread 4 call subtract() whilst either Thread1-3 are executing the add() method? But not sure if i demonstrated that in this code..
And also if both add() and subtract() methods were both syncrhonized, does that mean ONLY one thread has access to all the synchronhized methods in the object? E.g. Thread A is in the add() method, Thread B CANNOT call the subtract() method?

Answer (score 0):

> if Thread1-3 are calling the add() method in turn (due to the lock), can Thread 4 call subtract() whilst either Thread1-3 are executing the add() method?

Yes, it can. If you made `subtract` modify the `counter` in some way you would likely see the end result is not what you expect.

> if both add() and subtract() methods were both syncrhonized, does that mean ONLY one thread has access to all the synchronhized methods in the object?

Also yes. In this scenario, access to the two methods is protected by the same lock. If one thread hold the lock because it's executing `add()`, another thread that calls `subtract()` has to wait.

> E.g. Thread A is in the add() method, Thread B CANNOT call the subtract() method?

It can *call* it, but it has to wait until the lock is released to run any code within the method.